# Accidentally deleted /opt, how do I create it again?

Tags: filesystem, directory

I am new to Ubuntu, today I was learning how to delete files and folders but accidentally I deleted the `/opt` directory that located in Computer.

I don’t know if what I deleted is important or not. So I want to create the `/opt` directory again. where all other important folder exists and they are `/var`,`/root`, `/home` and so on.

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x   5 root     root      4096 sep 28 07:28 opt` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a newly installed Ubuntu system, `/opt` exists but is empty. You can just run:

```
sudo mkdir /opt
```

And that will recreate it, with the correct permissions.

But if there was software installed inside when it was removed, that won't bring it back.

There probably wasn't, though. You'd likely have remembered installing it there. `/opt` is not usually for programs installed automatically through Ubuntu's package manager. Instead, for the most part it's used for programs that install with their own methods, often (but not only) proprietary payware installed from CD.

If you remember how you deleted `/opt`, a more specific prediction as to whether or not there was anything in it could be given. For example, if the way you remove it was to run `sudo rmdir /opt`, that will only work if the directory is empty. On the other hand, if you used `rm -r`, it needn't have been empty.

Comment: thnx. its works ..

Comment: +1 --- The only well-known and quite popular software I know that install itself on `/opt` is [calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) (barring a couple of microcontroller-developing things that I do not think matter here).

Comment: Google Chrome also installs itself under /opt/

Comment: @Rmano there are more: teamviewer, jasperserver.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check what files may have been deleted with `dpkg -S /opt` or `grep ^/opt /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list`. It should give you a list of packages that might need to be reinstalled. If none is, then just recreate the directory with a simple `sudo mkdir /opt`. You may also check if you have installed packages manually in those directories, but that's very tricky.